# static classes vs singleton, common practice?

Tags: php, singleton, static-classes

I usually use static classes such as :

```
class Manager {
  static $parameter1 = null;
  static $parameter2 = null;

  public static function return_something () {
    return 'param1 : ' . $parameter1;
  }
}
```

in my code for parametric and functional classes such as application's Managers.

Until now, I was coding this way because it seemed logical to me but I decided to question myself recently because I know there is also Singleton-like programming practice.

Anyways I've always been involved in **small** projects on myself, so I quite struggle to answer this wonder :

Is it good practice to use static classes for parametric entities ? Or should I switch to Singleton programming ?

> **I was browsing in the already asked related questions but I couldn't**
> **find my gold. All the already asked posts are answered on the**
> **thread-safe level. What about the performances (both memory and speed)**
> **?**
>
> **Or in your opinion and your experience in large projects, which**
> **strategy seems to kick code productivity up ?**

Answer (score -2):

As far as i see it could be one interesting way to write a program and all it matters about the project if many people are involved in a project, then they should be aware or familiar with your coding norms otherwise wise they will be confused. Isn't overall OOPs concept just a set of rules to make coding challenging and intersting ?

take this scenario of "IF"

```
if(a == true){
}
else{
}
```

or

```
(a == true)?'matched':'else'
```

both are same but I have been advised to use the first scenario as it will make coding good to read or understand to others.

+1 for doing something different.